# Wordpress plugins not working with custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-theme

I'm new to WordPress and actually repairing a page as a favour. The page was originally created by an inexperienced developer which is why it has its faults.

My main concern is that I don't seem to get any of the plugins to work. The page has a custom theme. I tried switching to a previously uploaded theme and all the plugins worked like a charm on that.

The client seems reluctant to abandon the custom theme and short of having to take it apart piece by piece I'm trying my luck here.

Both `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` are called and seem to be in the right places, `wp_head()` right before the `</head>` tag and `wp_footer()` right before the `</body>` tag.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general question, but here are some starting steps to try and see how you get on...

In wp-config.php add or alter the following: `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`
This enables debuging to screen and will throw up any errors.

I would still advise you then try the plugins one by one - in theory once you get one working then the others should be ok. There is more to a theme than just having wp_head() etc... make sure the loop is in place and things like get_sidebar(). Compare whole pages to those of a working theme.

Comment: I don't even have sidebars, it's a VERY basic layout, I've got header.php, footer.php. index.php, a custom php file and one css file to work with. Perhaps the theme is too broken to function.

Comment: What happens when you enable wp_debug? do you get any errors?